# Get value of comboboxitem contentcontrol in wpf

Tags: wpf, combobox, selecteditem, contentcontrol

I am new to WPF.
I want to know how can i get the selectedtext if the text that i want is placed inside a control inside comboboxitem and not directly inside comboboxitem.
I know this is very basic,but would appreciate if someone could provide me a simple and quick solution

My simple combobox code is as follows:

```
<ComboBox x:Name="cmdTest">
    <ComboBoxItem>
        <TextBlock Text="RED" Background="RED" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Sans Serif" FontSize="14"/>
    </ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>
        <Grid Width="250">
            <TextBlock Text="GREEN" Background="GREEN" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Sans Serif" FontSize="14" Height="15"/>
        </Grid>
    </ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem>
        <TextBlock Text="BLUE" Background="Blue" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Sans Serif" FontSize="14"/>
    </ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Comment: Are you using MVVM?

Comment: Description is not clear.

Comment: tx Mighty badaboom,yes in actual project i will  be using MVVM.So wud request if you cud provide an MVVVM based solution also..but as short and as simple since i am an absolute newbie to this..:-).

Answer (score 0):

**XAML:**

```
<ComboBox Name="anyname" SelectionChanged="cmbColors_SelectionChanged">
```

**C#:**

```
private void cmbColors_SelectionChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Controls.SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show(string.Format("Selected Item: {0}", anyname.Text));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
private void cmdTest_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
    ComboBoxItem item = cmdTest.SelectedItem as ComboBoxItem;
    if (item != null)
    {
        TextBlock txt = item.Content as TextBlock;
        if (txt != null)
            MessageBox.Show(txt.Text + " is selected");
    }
}
```

Comment: tx..this worked for me for now. :-).
just one more question ..
when bi run my application and  the combobox shows up with the current xaml,though i have applied the HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" attribute in the combobox as suggested above,the background color of the comboboxitem still leaves a few pixels uncolored on either side of the combobox item.
Is there some xaml attribute or anything that can cover that too?
tx in advance`:-).

Comment: Please ask a new question if you have another issue.

Answer (score 0):

First change your xaml code:`<ComboBox x:Name="cmdTest"  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" SelectedValuePath="Text">
            <ComboBoxItem Padding="0" >
                <TextBlock Text="RED" Background="RED" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Sans Serif" FontSize="14"/>
            </ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Padding="0">
                <TextBlock  Text="GREEN" Background="GREEN" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Sans Serif" FontSize="14" Height="15"/>
            </ComboBoxItem>
            <ComboBoxItem Padding="0">
                <TextBlock  Text="BLUE" Background="Blue" Foreground="White" FontFamily="Sans Serif" FontSize="14"/>
            </ComboBoxItem>
        </ComboBox>`

After for get text value use:

```
 var z = cmdTest.Text.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(z);
```

Comment: tx..this worked for me for now. :-).
just one more question ..
when i run my application and  the combobox shows up with the current xaml,though i have applied the HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" attribute in the combobox as suggested above,the background color of the comboboxitem still leaves a few pixels uncolored on either side of the combobox item.
Is there some xaml attribute or anything that can cover that too?
tx in advance`:-).